# Getting InsufficientPrivilegesException when deploying CloudFormation stack to create an ElasticBeanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I've written a CloudFormation template that creates an ElasticBeanstalk application.  However, when I execute the template, I receive the following error: `Access Denied (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InsufficientPrivilegesException; Request ID: 6c580af3-250d-4658-bc2f-8f6af4c1dd6d; Proxy: null)`.

What permission do I need to add?

The relevant portion of my CloudFormation script:

```
# The role used by CloudFormation to create the stack
CFNRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Action: ["sts:AssumeRole"]
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [cloudformation.amazonaws.com]
      Version: "2012-10-17"
    Path: /
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: CloudFormationRole
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Action:
                - "ec2:*"
                - "elasticbeanstalk:*"
                - "iam:*"
                - "lambda:*"
                - "logs:*"
              Effect: Allow
              Resource: "*"

# more stuff here... 

# Create the EB app without an Environment for now
EBApp1:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
  Properties:
    Description: my-api
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing the S3 permissions on the CFNRole. I modified the permissions to the following, and the stack could be deployed.

```
CFNRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Action: ["sts:AssumeRole"]
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [cloudformation.amazonaws.com]
      Version: "2012-10-17"
    Path: /
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: CloudFormationRole
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Action:
                - "ec2:*"
                - "elasticbeanstalk:*"
                - "iam:*"
                - "lambda:*"
                - "logs:*"
                - "s3:*" #### Added this line ####
              Effect: Allow
              Resource: "*"
```